# Ionic cordova plugin suddenly not installed

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3

Suddenly when building and running my Ionic 3 app from Xcode I get an error like this, for all cordova plugins:

```
WARN: Native: tried calling StatusBar.styleDefault, but the StatusBar plugin is not installed.
WARN: Install the StatusBar plugin: 'ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar'
```

It was working fine so far, I don't understand why this is happening now and how to remedy (except re-installing).

Even though they are well listed in both package.json and config.xml.

Comment: Is there a `plugins` folder in your root directory with a folder for every plugin you use?

Comment: try `ionic cordova platform update ios`

Comment: @David yes the plugin folder is present and filled correctly...

Comment: @SwapnilPatwa after trying `ionic cordova platform update ios`I get the following: `CDVPlugin class CDVSplashScreen (pluginName: SplashScreen) does not exist.
[1314:318257] ERROR: Plugin 'SplashScreen' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.`

Comment: Then just `rm -rf platforms` and `cordova platform add ios`. Sometimes you just need to kill everything to make it work again. If thats not enough also remove the `plugins` and `node_modules` folders and readd everything.

Comment: @David instead of `rm -rf platforms` wouldn't it be better to use `cordova platform rm ios`?

Comment: That kind of does the same thing it only also removes the reference in `config.xml` and `package.json` AFAIK.

Comment: @David I tried `rm -rf platforms`and `cordova paltform add ios` which almost worked but led to duplicate error in the Xcode linker. So for future reference, I did the following, which worked this time `rm -rf platforms` + `ionic cordova platform rm ios` + `ionic cordova platform add ios`. I guess Ionic is adding some additional steps that prevent the duplicate error. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!